# Whitelist Azure Databricks SQL Warehouse access to selected tables

Tags: azure, databricks

Is there an option to allow a service principal (SP) that accesses Azure Databricks SQL Warehouse using a personal access token (PAT) to restrict access only to selecting data from present tables and disable access to anything else?

**Example**

We want the SP to query tables inside Azure Databricks SQL Warehouse:

```sql
--- should have read access to any table
SELECT * FROM hive_metastore.my_schema.my_table;
```

However, we want to restrict access to anything else:

```sql
--- should not be possible even if SQL Warehouse has access
SELECT * FROM delta.`abfss://some_path`
```

```sql
--- anything other than querying tables should not be possible
CREATE TABLE hive_metastore.my_schema.my_table;
DROP TABLE hive_metastore.my_schema.my_table;
```

**Why we want it**

We want to use Azure Databricks SQL Warehouse for storing data that will be accessed from an external service that is not under our control. In this setup, we want the external service to be able to read only the tables inside the SQL Warehouse and not to be able to execute any other SQL commands.

**Our setup**

- Hive metastore table access control enabled
- Unity catalog disabled

**How the external service accesses our SQL Warehouse**

Using the JDBC URL and the service principals' personal access token.